# case when in select doesn't return column value

Tags: sql, hadoop

I'm trying to do:

1. when Account.Id=Case.Student_Id -> return Account.Name value in column "Student_Name"
2. when Account.Id=Case.Faculty_Id -> return Account.Name value in column "Faculty_Name"
3. Account contains both Student & Faculty
4. Student_Name & Faculty_Name must be in separate columns

When I use the below Case in SELECT, both Student_Name & Faculty_Name are all null:

```
select a2.id as Case_Id,
       case when a1.id=a2.Student_Id then a1.name end as Student_Name,
       case when a1.id=a2.Faculty_Id then a1.name end as Faculty_Name
from account a1, case a2
```

I know from the below SQL that there're matches on a1.Id=a2.Student_Id + a1.Id=a2.Faculty_Id:

```
select a2.id, a1.name
from account a1, case a2
where a1.id=a2.Student_Id
```

Any idea on why I don't get column "Student_Name", "Faculuty_Name" are null? I'm using Claudera Hadoop.

Comment: What *database* are you using?  Hadoop is not a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get names for two columns, you would do:

```
select c.id as Case_Id, a1.name as Student_Name, a2.name as  Faculty_Name
from case c account c left join
     account a1 
     on c.student_id = a1.id left join
     account a2
     on c.faculty_id = a2.id;
```

This is my best interpretation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yup, it gets the results I wanted. Edited SQL: select c.id as Case_Id, a1.name as Student_Name, a2.name as  Faculty_Name
from t_case c left join
     account a1 
     on c.student_id = a1.id left join
     account a2
     on c.faculty_id = a2.id;